# Converting raw Bayer images from HQ camera with dcraw throws error: Cannot decode file

Tags: camera, picamera

**Hardware**

- Raspberry Pi 4 Model B (4 GB RAM)
- Raspberry Pi HQ Camera (12 MP, Sony IMX477R)

**Software**

- [raspiraw](https://github.com/raspberrypi/raspiraw)
- [dcraw](https://github.com/6by9/dcraw)

I want to capture raw images with RPI HQ camera to achieve greater fps at full resoltion (4056x3040) as described [here](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=284937#p1724700).

I first take an image with `raspiraw -o image.raw`, which generates a `image.raw` file.

Then I want to convert the raw Bayer data to an image file with `dcraw image.raw`. But this command throws an error: `Cannot decode file image.raw`

Comment: I'd like to suggest using the -v (verbose) flag to get more messages. You should edit your question with this new information.

Comment: Unfortunately, `dcraw -v image.raw` only outputs `Cannot decode file image.raw`, too

Comment: But if you examine the output, it will probably give more detailed error messages.

Comment: Sorry, but I read your comment incorrectly. Unfortunately, I don't have access to a pi right now nor a camera, so I'm out of suggestions.

Comment: Is there anything in the log files?